# Set DragFeature events

Tags: openlayers

I have a drag feature. If i set the drag events when i construct the drag feature object it's working very well:

```
var dragFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(pointsLayer,
        {
            onStart:function (feature, pixel){
                //Do stuf
            }
            ,
            onComplete: function(feature, pixel){
                //Do stuff
            }
        });
```

The problem is that i want to change those events after i create the object, or i want to do a little bit more onComplete (so i want a default action and be able to add a new action).

I tried with

```
dragFeature.events.on(
        {   
            onComplete: function(feature){
            alert(feature);
            }
        }
);
```

But this is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions are also values, you may simply call a function which may be redefined when you desire. Pseudocode:

```
onComplete: function(feature) {
  // Do common stuff
  // ...
  dragOnCompleteDoMore(feature);
  // Where dragOnCompleteDoMore has been changed before the drag was started depending on some criteria.
}
```

Comment: That's an solution for sure, but i was actually looking for a way to set the onComlete function on OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature ofter the object is created using the constructor.

Comment: Well then reassign the function it is part of the properties: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragFeature-js.html

Comment: That's what i was looking for! Easy actually :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for:

```
dragFeature.onStart=function(){
}
```

TX!!!